# How to use variables in psql LIKE query regular expression

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

I have a psql database with two tables that I want to join for a query. Table 1 (we can called Articles) has two columns:

- slug - which is the name of the article path in the website

  - example 1 - 'my-article-1'
  - example 2 - 'my-article-2'
- title - the actual title of the article

  - example 1 - 'My first article'
  - example 2 - 'My second article'

Table 2 (we will call Log) has two columns which together represents request responses sent back from the server:

- url - which is the url path requested by GET

  - example 1 - '/articles/my-article1'
  - example 2 - '/articles/my-article2'
- status - which is the status code send back from server

  - example - '200 OK'

I want to return the number of times that a specific article has been requested and returned a '200 OK' status code.

My Problem:
I want to match the Articles.slug variable to the Log.url variable in my where clause, but I don't know how to use variables in regular expressions. Right now I'm just working on matching the slug to the path, here is my code so far:

```
SELECT articles.title, articles.slug, log.path
FROM articles, log
WHERE log.path like '/articles/' + articles.slug
and log.status = '200 OK'
```

I know that my WHERE clause is incorrect, that's what I'm looking for. How do I match the full log.path string to a concatenated string with a variable, articles.slug.

Sorry if any of this is unclear or looks stupid, I'm learning SQL for the first time <3

Comment: In your example your `slug` is `'my-article-1'` and your `url` (or is it `path`, which is what your query uses?) is `'/articles/my-article1'`. Note that there once is a dash before the number and once it isn't. Is that a typo her or is the real data like that? That would explain why your query doesn't work. If it's just a typo here the query actually should work when you replace `+` with `||` which is Postgres' string concatenation operator. You should also use explicit join syntax over implicit one an your `LIKE` can be replaced with `=`.

Comment: I was just using the - to separate the words "example 1" from the actual example, it was not actually in my query. Look at my code example for how I actually made my query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution that doesn't exactly answer my question, but here's how I got around it.

```
select articles.title, count(*)
from articles, log
where substring(log.path,10,100) = articles.slug
and log.status = '200 OK'
group by articles.title
```

Comment: You probably want `from articles join log on substring(log.path,10,100) = articles.slug` instead of the old-school implicit JOIN. You can JOIN on pretty much any expression after all.

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax with an `ON` clause.  Your query should look more like this:

```
SELECT a.title, a.slug, l.path
FROM articles a JOIN
     log l
     ON l.path like '/articles/' || a.slug
WHERE l.status = '200 OK';
```

`||` is the concatenation operator in Postgres and most other databases -- because it is the ISO/ANSI standard operator for string concatenation.